Plotting the displacement-time graph of a body
Suppose a body starts from point $A$ at a uniform speed of $1$ m/s. Here is the break-up of its motion:

It first travels north $3$ m.
Then it turns right and travels $4$ m.
Then it again turns right and travels $3$ m.
It turns right again and travels $4$ m reaching the starting position.
Finally, it travels further $4$ m towards the west and reaches B.

I need to plot the displacement-time graph of this body. I can plot the graph till the body returns to the starting position, but I don't know whether I should take the further $4$ m towards the west as positive or negative in the displacement-time graph. I've already taken the north direction to be positive.


If you have already established the positive and negative sides for this problem, then you should keep that direction as negative. Think of this as a compass and you are heading due West. Compared to the east, this is in the negative direction and you have gone a total negative distance from your starting point (A)
